# Printer Setup can not find printer over wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

I'm using the Canon IR-ADV c5030 setup program and when it comes to the point of searching for the printer, it can not find it, if my PC is connected to the network by WIFI.  If I'm connected by an actual ethernet cable, the printer is found and everything works smoothly.  What is going on here?  How can I get this to work over WIFI?

We have some new laptops that actually don't have an ethernet jack.  So, the cable isn't an option there.

Some other points:

After installing the printer over ethernet, printing over WIFi will work fine.

Sending scanned documents from the printer to my PC over WIFI doesn't work.  Once again, if plugged in, works fine.

My IP details of both ethernet and wireless from IPConfig:

[image]

Also, the IP address for the printer (or, at least, the web interface) is: 192.168.1.31.

Not sure about my network details or where to look, but if relevant, tell me where to look and I'll get that info.

Comment: Are the wired and WiFi devices on the same network? Check the IP address of a PC under both connections. Also, you have a contradiction: you say the PC cannot find the printer over WiFi, yet WiFi printing works fine.

Comment: @hdhondt Thanks for the point about contradiction. I've updated answer to clarify this: "After installing the printer over ethernet, printing over WIFi will work fine."  Also, the device is the same laptop(s).  Just sometimes use an ethernet cable and sometimes just WiFi.

Comment: But you didn't answer my question: what is the PC's IP address when connected WiFi and wired? Check it by typing IPCONFIG at a DOS prompt.

Comment: @hdhondt I've added the IP details from IPConfig to the end of the question.

Comment: How come the Ethernet and wireless subnets are so wildly different? (e.g. 192.168.1.x and 192.168.11.x) - This is probably why it works fine on Ethernet and not through wireless... Is this a business network? Ideally a business network should use equipment that allows either multiple SSIDs so that you can have a "secure" wireless that can then let you use the same subnet for Ethernet and wireless devices (they all come under 192.168.1.x for example) or will allow routes to be configured so that your wireless devices can communicate with the ethernet subnet and get the printers working.

Comment: This is a business network.  But the network was setup this way before I got here.  It's entirely possible that it was setup by someone was wasn't very experienced.  We do have a server rack in the office that includes the wireless and ethernet cables that eventually come from the VoIP company.

Comment: I've added the printer IP address

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a workaround:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Devices and Printers
2. Add Printers & Scanners
3. Click The printer that I want isn't listed
4. Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname Click Next

Printer should be found